# Как яндекс танком отправлять json в post запросе?

Tags: json, яндекс-танк

Yandex tank +phantom +ammo.txt

Как сгенерировать и отправить yandex tank'ом post запрос c json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для генерации json запросов yandex танком нужно взять официальный ammo generator https://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ammo_generators.html

Заменить в нем в 48й строке hostname.com на целевой адрес и 51-ю строку

```
 51             Connection: close\r\n
```

на эти две строки:

```
 51             "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" + \
 52             "Connection: keep-alive"
```

Получится:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/python
  2 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
  3 
  4 import sys
  5 
  6 def make_ammo(method, url, headers, case, body):
  7     """ makes phantom ammo """
  8     #http request w/o entity body template
  9     req_template = (
 10           "%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
 11           "%s\r\n"
 12           "\r\n"
 13     )
 14 
 15     #http request with entity body template
 16     req_template_w_entity_body = (
 17           "%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
 18           "%s\r\n"
 19           "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
 20           "\r\n"
 21           "%s\r\n"
 22     )
 23 
 24     if not body:
 25         req = req_template % (method, url, headers)
 26     else:
 27         req = req_template_w_entity_body % (method, url, headers, len(bo        dy), body)
 28 
 29     #phantom ammo template
 30     ammo_template = (
 31         "%d %s\n"
 32         "%s"
 33     )
 34 
 35     return ammo_template % (len(req), case, req)
 36 
 37 def main():
 38     for stdin_line in sys.stdin:
 39         try:
 40             method, url, case, body = stdin_line.split("||")
 41             body = body.strip()
 42         except:
 43             method, url, case = stdin_line.split("||")
 44             body = None
 45 
 46         method, url, case = method.strip(), url.strip(), case.strip()
 47 
 48         headers = "Host: hostname.com\r\n" + \
 49             "User-Agent: tank\r\n" + \
 50             "Accept: */*\r\n" + \
 51             "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" + \
 52             "Connection: keep-alive"
 53 
 54         sys.stdout.write(make_ammo(method, url, headers, case, body))
 55 
 56 if __name__ == "__main__":
 57     main()
```

Сгенерировать post запрос с json в ammo.txt командой:

**echo "POST||/uri/path|||| {\"key\":\"value\", \"key\":\"value\"}" | ./make_ammo.py > ammo.txt**

Создать конфиг load.yaml:

```
  1 phantom:
  2   address: hostname.com:443 # [Target's address]:[target's port]
  3   ammo_type: phantom
  4   load_profile:
  5     load_type: rps # schedule load by defining requests per second
  6     schedule: line(1, 10, 10m) # starting from 1rps growing linearly to         10rps during 10 minutes
  7   ssl: true
  8 console:
  9   enabled: true # enable console output
 10 telegraf:
 11   enabled: false # let's disable telegraf monitoring for the first time
```

В данном случае трафик направляется на 433 порт по ssl.

Запускаем танк командой

**yandex-tank -c load.yaml ammo.txt**

Answer (score 0):

В ammo.txt нужно в сумме байт пакета и значении Content-Length учитывать, что символы кириллицы весят 2 байта, поэтому за каждый символ прибавляйте к сумме байт +1, а в остальном передача происходит также как через Postman:

**load.yaml:**

```
phantom:
      enabled: true
      package: yandextank.plugins.Phantom
      address: blabla:8080
      ssl: true
      ammofile: ammo.txt
      writelog: all
      load_profile:
        load_type: rps
        schedule: line(1, 10, 1m)
```

**ammo.txt:**

```
557 auth
POST /api/v3/ClientName HTTP/1.1
Authorization: bearer <Token>
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: blabla:8080
Content-Length: 27

{"Id": 1,"Name":"Вася"}
```